# Number of $2$-Sylow subgroups in $A_4 \times S_4$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> In $A_4 \times S_4$, is it possible to have three $2$-Sylow subgroups?

We know that $|A_4 \times S_4|=2^5 \cdot 3^2$ ; |$2$-Sylow| $= 32$ and |$3$-Sylow| $= 9$.

I found that the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups is $16$, but the number of $2$-Sylow subgroups is $3$ ; makes it  $(2^5) - 1=31$ & $31 \cdot 3=93$ but $93+(9×16=144) =237$ which isn't $288$!…

Comment: Yes it has three Sylow $2$-subgroups. Their union contains $63$ non-identity elements, not $93$. There are $80$ elements of order $3$ and $96$ of order $6$.

Comment: When counting the number of elements of a union of sets, make sure you don't count the elements of the intersections double. See the [inclusion - exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)